# psql undefined table, relation does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

```
/Users/0okyleo0/.gem/ruby/2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:822:in `async_exec': PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "events" does not exist (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
LINE 5:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"events"'::regclass
                                      ^
```

Is the issue everytime i try to open my ruby terminal menu for my test. i'm working in active records. i get this error everytime i try to use a method to add a event to a database.

```
def add_event
    puts "What is your event's name?\n\n"
    event_name = gets.chomp
    puts "What is your event's location?\n\n"
    event_location = gets.chomp
    puts "What is your start date? example: 1990-11-16\n\n"
    event_start_date = gets.chomp
    puts "What is your end date? example: 1990-11-19\n\n"
    event_end_date = gets.chomp
    Event.create({name: event_name, location: event_location,
        start_date: event_start_date, end_date: event_end_date})
    puts "#{name} has been added!"
end
```

this is my schema -

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140830232637) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "event_tables", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "location"
    t.datetime "start_date"
    t.datetime "end_date"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using a model class called `Event`:

```
Event.create({name: event_name, location: event_location,
        start_date: event_start_date, end_date: event_end_date})
```

and that wants to use a table called `events` unless you've configured it otherwise. But you've created a table called `event_tables`:

```
create_table "event_tables", force: true do |t|
  ..
end
```

You should use a table called `events` or a model called `EventTable`.

Comment: Ok, thanks! i'll try and make a new migration to rename the table.